# dell chromebook 11, установка linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ос, bios

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо установить на данное устройство какой то дистрибутив linux. Уже все перерыл. Нашел способ выставления приоритетов загрузки, от рута приписывал crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 dev_boot_legacy=1 и после перезагрузки CTRL+L ничего не происходит, хотя должна загрузка с usb. Как мне удалить chrome os и установить что то другое?

Comment: Попробуйте этот метод установки:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Chromebook_11

Comment: попробуйте так: https://habrahabr.ru/post/204452/

Comment: Дело в том, что в ноутбуке отсутствует wifi модуль, а внешний к хром ос прикрутить не удалось. Вот и хочу поставить какой то дистрибутив линукс вместо хром ос с флешки.