# Отключение write protect на Dell Chromebook 11

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ос

Здравствуйте

Я выкрутил write protect винт, но команда flashrom --wp-disable выдает мне ошибку

> w25q_disable_writeprotect(): error=1

В чем проблема? Я уже перечитал кучу статей, форумов и ответ так и не нашел. Может кто сталкивался.
Помогите.

Comment: Не хватает исходных данных. Что такое *винт*? О каком железе идёт речь? Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: В хромбуках присутствует винт защиты от записи, и прежде чем производить какие либо манипуляции(вроде установки другой ос) необходимо его извлечь, и выключить защиту от записи. Винт я удалил, а защита от записи командой flashrom --wp-disable не выключается и возвращает ошибку указанную выше.

Comment: Обновите постинг этой информацией, а так же напишите зачем вы запускаете `flashrom`. Вы пытаетесь прошивку поменять?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682587/dell-chromebook-11-установка-linux